# iTunes crashes when I press refresh on the podcast pane

Tags: itunes, crash, podcasts

I'm using Mac OS 10.6.8 and I guess I've updated iTunes recently to 10.5 (141).

I pretty much only use iTunes to get my daily fix of podcasts and now it won't get new episodes and just crashes when I ask for a manual update.

I'm not syncing to any device and I've to tried to reset the store cache at the Advanced Preferences (no result).

Comment: I'm getting mad, the podcast pane doesn't group the podcasts anymore and the export .opml feature isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like after the last iTunes update a second empty Podcast item appeared on the left side column. The original Podcast pane started crashing as described on the original question.

I've delete the original Podcast item from the left column (it seems the application treated it as a sort of legacy playlist). And re-subscribed manually to all my podcasts (the new subscriptions get to appear in the new item).

After some frustration, it all seems to work again now.